# Kia Rio squeaks like a mouse when turning left

Tags: kia, wheel-bearing, rio, frontend

I have a 2014 Kia Rio. When I turn left it squeaks like a mouse. A very soft high pitched smooth squeak that is cyclical. The faster I go the faster the squeak.

What are some things I should consider investigating?

Comment: Is this squeak from the front of the vehicle?

Comment: It seems like it. It is definitely from the right side.